# Sparql query to match unique item identifier from wikidata

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'm trying to get properties value for a given wikidita item from the identifier unique identifier (e.g. wd:Q200639).

Let's say I want Paul Valéry's birth date (https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q200639). Is it possible to write a query like this one ?

```
SELECT ?birth
WHERE {
  wd:Q200639 <property i'm looking for> ?person.
  ?person wdt:P569 ?birth .
}
```

I can't manage to find a property that could do this in the docs. I guess my approach isn't the right one, any hint to help ?

Comment: the RDF data model is "subject-predicate-object", Paul would be the subject, the property for birth date would be the predicate and you leave the value for the data itself open aka use a variable. That's basically it for those direct facts asserted to an entity

Comment: `wd:Q200639 wdt:P569 ?birth .` is all you need

Comment: Thanks ! If I need to query other properties than birthdate I have to repeat the subjet ? Like `wd:Q200639 wdt:P569 ?birth . wd:Q200639 wdt:P570 ?death .`
I'm sure there must be a less redundant way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the subject (`wd:Q200639`) and the property (`wdt:P569`), you can include both in the triple pattern, and use a variable only for the value you want to find out (i.e., the birthdate):

```
wd:Q200639 wdt:P569 ?birthdate .
```

If you want to query multiple properties, instead of repeating the subject, you can use a semicolon (`;`):

```
wd:Q200639 wdt:P569 ?birthdate ;
           wdt:P570 ?deathdate .
```

If, for example, having a deathdate is optional, this is not possible, though. You would have to repeat the subject inside `OPTIONAL {}`:

```
wd:Q200639 wdt:P569 ?birthdate .
OPTIONAL { wd:Q200639 wdt:P570 ?deathdate . }
```

To avoid having to repeat the subject IRI, you can use `BIND` or `VALUES` to replace it with a variable:

```
# with BIND, you can only have one value
BIND( wd:Q200639 AS ?person ) .

?person wdt:P569 ?birthdate .
OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P570 ?deathdate . }
```

```
# with VALUES, you can have multiple, space-separated values
VALUES ?person { wd:Q200639 }

?person wdt:P569 ?birthdate .
OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P570 ?deathdate . }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your anwser has been really usefull !